# Conditional expectation of a uniform distribution given a geometric distribution

Tags: conditional-expectation

Let N follow a geometric distribution with probability p. After the success of the experiment we define X, a uniform distribution from 1 to N. Both distributions are discrete. Find E[X|N].

Comment: What is the formula for $E[X|N]$? Please state it, so we can confirm you know  it.

Comment: Since E[N]=1/p I have assumed that X is uniformly distributed from 1 to 1/p thus E[X|N]=p+1/2*p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Find $\mathbb E[X\mid N=n]$.

This is an expression in $n$ and if we set $f(n)=E[X\mid N=n]$ then $\mathbb E[X\mid N]=f(N)$.